# sum of values larger than median of each row in pandas dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, statistics, dataframe

Is there an efficient way to find the sum of values whose absolute value is larger than the median of the row in a pandas data frame?

For example:

```
      Monday    Tuesday    Wednesday  Thursday   Friday   Saturday
 0     2.2       4.4       0.5         9         4         3
 1     2         4         1           8         4         5
 2     1.8       4.5       0.9         8         1         15
 3     4         1         5           10        4         5
 …
```

How to generate the sum of numbers in each row which are larger than the median of the corresponding row? What about 25 percentile or 75 percentile?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

And to enhance @EdChum's answer to get the quantiles:

```
quantile = 0.75  # 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, etc.
df[df.gt(df.quantile(q=quantile, axis=1), axis=0)].sum(axis=1)
```

Given that there are only seven days in a week, I'm not sure if this will do as intended unless you have more columns than shown.  Do you want the quantiles by column instead of row?

Answer (score 4):

I think you want this:

```
In [19]:

df[df.gt(df.median(axis=1), axis=0)]
Out[19]:
   Monday  Tuesday  Wednesday  Thursday  Friday  Saturday
0     NaN      4.4        NaN         9       4       NaN
1     NaN      NaN        NaN         8     NaN         5
2     NaN      4.5        NaN         8     NaN        15
3     NaN      NaN          5        10     NaN         5
```

This uses [`.gt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.gt.html#pandas.DataFrame.gt) which is greater than and uses as the value the [`median`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.median.html#pandas.DataFrame.median) (row-wise by passing axis=1).

You can then call `sum` on this:

```
In [20]:

df[df.gt(df.median(axis=1), axis=0)].sum()
Out[20]:
Monday        NaN
Tuesday       8.9
Wednesday     5.0
Thursday     35.0
Friday        4.0
Saturday     25.0
dtype: float64
```

Comment: And to get the sum of such values for the rows, just tack on .sum(axis=1) to Ed's answer above.

Comment: Thanks Ed and Alex, never used '.gt' before. Just out of curiosity, is it possible to use 'apply' to realize the same function?

Comment: Yes you could but I'd advise against it because apply is slow whilst this will be vectorised, apply should be a last resort always

Answer (score 2):

Since you want to sum values in each row which is greater then median, and if you want to preserve Day values, below approach works fine

```
def func(row):
    return row[row>np.percentile(row, 50)].sum()
```

`func` function will be now applied on df

```
In [67]: df['rule'] = df.apply(func, axis=1)

In [68]: df
Out[68]:
   Monday  Tuesday  Wednesday  Thursday  Friday  Saturday  rule
0     2.2      4.4        0.5         9       4         3  17.4
1     2.0      4.0        1.0         8       4         5  13.0
2     1.8      4.5        0.9         8       1        15  27.5
3     4.0      1.0        5.0        10       4         5  20.0
```

And, for different quantiles, you could use [25, 50, 75] in `np.percentile(row, x)`